# Serilog filter not filtering on ResultDescription

Tags: c#, serilog

I have problem with filtering ResultDescription field with Serilog. It might be that I am doing something wrong.
Here is my code:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Async(x => x.Logger( (configureLogger) =>
    {
        configureLogger.Filter.ByExcluding("ResultDescription like '%Tesz log%'");
    }))
    .WriteTo.Async(x => x.Console(
        outputTemplate: "bla -> [{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
        theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code))
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .CreateLogger();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

I also tried a lambda expression in `ByExcluding`, but that didn't work either.
In my controller I am testing with the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
    logger.LogInformation("Teszt log!");  //I don't want to see this logs
    logger.LogInformation("I am logging!");
    return Ok("Test log has benn colled.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.Async(x => x.Logger((configureLogger) =>
{
    configureLogger.Filter.ByExcluding(logEvent => !logEvent.MessageTemplate.Text.ToLower().Contains("authenticationscheme: basicauthentication"));
    configureLogger.WriteTo.Async(x => x.Console(new ExpressionTemplate(
        template: "{@l:w4}: {SourceContext}\n" +
                      "{#if Scope is not null}" +
                    "\t{#each s in Scope}=> {s}{#delimit} {#end}\n" +
                    "{#end}" +
                    "\t {@m}\n" +
                    "{@x}",
        theme: TemplateTheme.Code)));
}))

.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogEventLevel.Warning)
.MinimumLevel.Debug()
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
.CreateLogger();
```